# If a cell is blank check for holiday date and set as 0 o 8.5, if it has a value to subtract from 8.5

Tags: excel, date, formula

I have 5 columns:

> Date, Day of Week, Logged Hrs, Time Due and Holidays

I am having issue getting the cells in the Time Due column to calculate some numbers.

If there is a cell value to subtract 8.5 hours from it to see if person owes time; also if the cell is blank to check if the date in the Date column is in the Holidays column, and if it is to show 8.5 if not to show 0.0.

Below is the formula I have been trying to use to check for the holiday but it has not been working, it does do the subtraction, but on the blank cell it does nothing

```
=IF(ISNA(INDEX(YEARS!J3:J16(MATCH('Agent Weekly Time Due'!N7,YEARS!J3:J16,0),0),1)),8.5,8.5-'Agent Weekly Time Due'!P7)
```

[image: Example image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are after:

```
=IF(AND(C2="",ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,E:E,0))),8.5,IF(C2<>"",8.5-C2,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks that is exctly what I needed.